# Accessing user profile info from Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Tags: azure, active-directory

I'm using this library to authenticate users I've added to the AAD portal

I'd like to be able to read profile info, e.g. a field I've added to check which company they belong to

To clarify my question, I've determined I can derive certain information, e.g. Name, from result.UserInfo

However, it seems to be only a limited subset - can't see any way of getting Contact Info fields

Code sample

IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr();

authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

PlatformParameters p = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, hwnd);

AuthenticationResult result = null;

result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, redirectURI, p);

if (result.IdToken != null)

{

Properties.Settings.Default.AuthToken = result.AccessToken;

UserInfo getProfile = new UserInfo(result.UserInfo); // THIS DOES NOT RETURN CONTACT INFO

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug - here is what we get with the user " + getProfile.GivenName);

Properties.Settings.Default.ValidKey = true;

Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

Globals.ThisAddIn.Token = result.AccessToken;

return "OK";
}

Comment: To get user info, you need to call Graph API.

Comment: Hmm, so I need to change how I'm authenticating the user completely in order to get the extra fields?

Comment: Well, I think you would need to acquire an access token for Azure AD Graph API or Microsoft Graph API and get the user object from there.

Comment: Legend - thanks a million! Took me ages but it's working now :)